# pynfc-AttributeError (Rpi)

Tags: python, attributes, raspberry-pi, nfc

After installing pynfc on our Raspberry pi running Raspbian, we encountered the following error after running the command `python mifareauth.py`:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/pi/uitgepakt/pynfc-0.0.4/pynfc.py", line 22, in 
>       NDO_HANDLE_CRC = nfc.NDO_HANDLE_CRC AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'NDO_HANDLE_CRC'

We couldn't find a solution to this problem. 
I hope someone can help us out.

Answer (score 0):

pynfc 0.0.4 is outdated; you will likely have better luck using the latest version, which can be obtained via Subversion as per the [instructions on the Google Code project pages](https://code.google.com/p/pynfc/source/checkout). Note however, that the project doesn't appear to have been maintained for almost two years, and libnfc (the underlying API that pynfc uses) has moved on a lot during that time. Significant code changes have required a lot of backward compatibility to be sacrificed, causing pynfc to no longer work with recent versions of libnfc.

At the time of writing, the latest version of pynfc is 0.0.7, which works perfectly with [libnfc 1.5.1](https://code.google.com/p/libnfc/source/browse/?name=libnfc-1.5.1). A small tweak may be required to get the latter working on the Raspberry Pi *if* your NFC hardware is connected via UART, which involves little more than adding Raspbian's default path to the device node (`/dev/ttyAMA0`) to `libnfc/buses/uart_posix.c`.